# Android Put Method error

Tags: java, android, put

I have tried sending message to server with `PUT` method but it doesn't work. can you solve this message : `java.net.ProtocolException: java cannot write request body after response has been read o`

```
class DoUpdateSlides extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String JSONData = params[0];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(API);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");

            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            int statusCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println(statusCode);

            OutputStream dos =  httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            dos.write(JSONData.getBytes());

            InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            String result = "";
            int byteCharacter;
            while ((byteCharacter = is.read())!=-1){
                result += (char)byteCharacter;
            }
            Log.d("json api","DoUpdateSlides.doInBackground Json return: "+ result);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And the stacktrace :

```
System.err: java.net.ProtocolException: cannot write request body after 
       response has been read
05-04 17:20:26.753 5631-5645/com.aden.vidit.learningcrud 
W/System.err: at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:203)
        at com.aden.vidit.learningcrud.EditActivity$DoUpdateSlides.doInBackground(EditActivity.java:137)
        at com.aden.vidit.learningcrud.EditActivity$DoUpdateSlides.doInBackground(EditActivity.java:121)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: what's the value for `API`? Do you have a stacktrace for us?

Comment: http://13.229.60.14:3000/slideshow and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP protocol is based on a request-response pattern. You send your request first and the server responds. Once the server responded, you can't send any more content, it wouldn't make sense.

When you call `getResponseCode()` you effectively tell the server that your request has finished and it can process it. If you want to send more data, you have to start a new request.

Move this code before calling `getResponseCode()`

```
OutputStream dos =  httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
dos.write(JSONData.getBytes());
```

And should close the connection once it is done(Use try and catch and close the connection in finally block).